# Mutual exclusion in concurrent process

Tags: java, concurrency

For examples, I have two programs likes this one:

Shared variables:

```
boolean f0 = false;
boolean f1 = false;
```

Program 0:

```
1. f0 = true;
2. while(f1==true){}
3. //Important section
4. f0 = false;
```

Program 1:

```
a. f1 = true;
b. while(f0==true){}
c. //Important section
d. f1 = false;
```

What I want to ask is that is there such a case that both processes can enter the Important section at the same time? Can you give me an example with specific code execution ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should clarify whether you mean thread or process.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I just edited it

Comment: How do you share the variables across "programs"? By program, do you mean process? This is confusing.

Comment: Just assump that this is possible.. The main thing here is I try to understand how this code is not mutual exlusion

Comment: It does make a difference. If these are really 2 processes, then you need to actively share the changes across processes and you can decide or not to allow interleaving to happen. If these are 2 threads, then the Java Memory Model applies, which has very specific rules.

Comment: Oh ok, let's think that they are two different processes and they access those variables from database. What I'm wondering is that at which situation, both programs can enter the important section at the same time

Comment: The code sample is too abstract for such a concrete questions you ask. How are you going to share `boolean` variables across **processes**?

Comment: This question is unanswerable until clarified.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, yes, for a myriad for reasons (caching, instruction reordering etc).

Comment: can you give me an real examples?

Comment: @assylias: Doesn't change a thing, as long as what we're looking at is Java code as the tags imply. :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though only process 0 writes to f0, process 1 may be reading f0 while process 0 is writing to it, so you can most definitely get both processes in the critical section.

You need to lookup the `synronized` keyword to learn how to handle multiple thread safely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can happen!

You can protect that section with

```
// this Object must be shared between both Threads.
Object lock = new Object();

synronized(lock) {

//  .. here protected

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are really separate processes, then their operation is completely independent of each other and so the answer is 'yes'.  Each has its own copy of all the variables.

Did you mean to ask about threads perhaps?  Anyway, the answer's the same unless you introduce a synchronization mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If this code was executed in sequentially consistent manner then the answer is **no**. There is no such execution order that allows these 2 threads to enter critical section simultaneously.

If we consider Java realm then yes, it is possible. Your threads don't use synchronisation in spite of they share some data. In this case JVM cannot guarantee they will ever observe each other writes.

But in any case this "mutex" is prone to deadlock. Consider this execution:

```
f0 = true;
f1 = true;
---------------------
while (f0) {}
while (f1) {}
```